# What do Crystal Reports arrays start indexing with?

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports

I am a crystal reports newcomer. I'm cleaning up some code from a previous person in Crystal reports who didn't understand the built-in strings at all and many times they needed do anything with a string they used *Split* to turn it into an array.

**Does crystal indexing start with 1 or 0?** It seems like it starts with 1 looking at this code but I can't find documentation on that.

I know many other programming language I've used arrays always start with index 0. I see that crystal is not like other languages and is made for people that aren't really programming oriented.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They start with 1. See the Crystal Reports help and search for "Arrays".